# Regex to check characters or integers at specific positions

Tags: regex

I want to check that in my string  **2-5-8 & 9 MUST BE ALPHA CHARACTERS & 1, 4, 7, 10 & 11 SHOULD BE NUMERIC,** and all the other positions can have both alpha or numeric.

I've written the following regex for it:

```
^(?:.{1}|.{4}|.{7}|.{8})([A-Z])(?:.{0}|.{3}|.{6}|.{9}|.{10})([0-9])$
```

If i don't combine these two capturing groups it works fine.

Here's an example for this regex test: https://regex101.com/r/k8rmSV/1

Comment: You can't tell the regex engine to jump at different positions on execution. The string is parsed from left to right. You may use lookarounds to some extent, but that is not what you need here. Just define the pattern position by position as per the requirements. Your current fiddle and pattern are very obscure. Please check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/VzYJLo/1).

Comment: Quite understanding.

Comment: Ali, I believe the answer below is not what you need. However, it is not clear what you need exactly. If you need more help, just edit the question to include more test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Wiktor just go through the string step by step

```
[A-Z][0-9].[0-9][A-Z].[0-9][A-Z][A-Z][0-9]
```

Check the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/k8rmSV/2) for more tests.

Comment: @AliSajid `.` matches any char - do you really need that behavior?